# Integral determines function behaviour

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, pr.probability

Let us define:

$f(t) = t^{-1} \int_{\mathbf{R}^{3}} Exp[-\frac{x^2}{2t}] h(x) dx,$

for a real function h. What can I say about this function if I know that

$f(t) \rightarrow 1$.

I think that the convergence implies that

$t \rightarrow \int_{B(t)} h(x) dx$  (where B(t) is a ball of radius t)

grows like $t^{1/2}$ but I do not know how prove it formally. Moreover I have a feeling that this question is so simple (at least in formulation) that must have been answered somewhere.

(my question seems to be analitic, I put it also on the probability forum as may be it is possible to use some tools for Gaussian distribution/processes).

Comment: Are you talking about the limit of $f(t)$ as $t\to\infty$? (@Steve: If it were the limit as $t\to0$ as you seem to think, the factor in front of the integral sign should be proportional to $t^{-3/2}$.)

Comment: Harald, you're right. I missed the $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

With $$H(r)=\int_{B(r)} h(x)\,dx$$ note that $H'(r)$ is the surface integral of $h$ over the sphere of radius $r$. Thus $$f(t)=t^{-1}\int_0^\infty H'(r)e^{-r^2/2t}\,dr=t^{-2}\int_0^\infty H(r)e^{-r^2/2t}r\,dr$$ after a partial integration, assuming $H$ does not have superexponential growth. The ansatz $H(r)=r^\gamma$ gives $$tf(t)=t^{-1}\int_0^\infty r^\gamma e^{-r^2/2t}\,dr=t^{-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(2xt)^{\gamma/2}t\,dx=2^{\gamma/2}\Gamma(\gamma/2+1)t^{\gamma/2},$$ and so it is the case $\gamma=2$ that corresponds to constant $f$. This argument can be weakened so the ansatz takes the form $H(r)=(1+o(1))r^\gamma$ as $r\to\infty$, and the above calculation should yield $tf(t)\sim\mathrm{const}\cdot t^{\gamma/2}$ (modulo details I haven't bothered with). So the case you are interested in seems to yield $\gamma=2$, not $\gamma=1/2$ as your question indicates.

(Edited to correct a mistake and provide more detailed calculations.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping though that there is more general way of answering such questions (e.g. via some sort of tauberian-like theory).

Comment: You can get the same conclusion under the assumption that $h\ge 0$. I'm not posting the details now because I do not know if this is of any use. It is, indeed, like "Tauberian theory", so we have to assume some regularity of $H$ to get the desired conclusion. Positivity of $h$ implies that $H$ is increasing. You can, probably, get away with even milder additional assumptions but not without any. So, what exactly do you know about your $h$?